# .after() method in tkinter only gets called once

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make an infinite loop using the Tkinter root.after() method. idealy the loop function should be called every second. But the function in the second argument of after is only getting called once. Am I missing something concerning .after or is .after the wrong approach on to begin with?

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
def loop():
  print("hello World")
root.after(1000, loop)
root.mainloop()
```

This code only prints "hello World" once instead of the desired call every second

Comment: You need to call `after(...)` at the end of `loop()`.

Comment: If you want the function to be called periodically, you need to put another call to `.after()` inside it.

Comment: What you describe is the documented behavior of `after` - call it once, and it runs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()


def loop():
    print("hello World")
    # once 'loop()' is called from root, it will get called again here
    root.after(1000, loop)


root.after(1000, loop)  # initial call to start 'loop()'
# EDIT to clarify that you could just call 'loop' to start things up; no need for 'after'
# loop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `after(1000, loop)` should be `root.after(1000, loop)` inside `loop()`.

Comment: @acw1668 You're right! Fixed it!